# How to apply a function to multible column in a np.ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Problem:
I have two np.ndarray (2000, ) and another (2000, 7). And I have a function which should work with those np.ndarrays. It works perfectly fine with the Data Set (2000, ) but doesnt work with the other one

Function:

```
def smooth_ma(
    price: np.ndarray,
    period: Union[int, List[int]],
    ffill: bool = False,
) -> np.ndarray:
    """Compute Wilder's Moving Average indicator.

    Parameters
    ----------
    price
        Contains securities price data.
    period
        Lookback period(s) used in order to compute the indicator.
    ffill
        If True, propagate last valid computation forward

    Returns
    -------
    np.ndarray
        Indicator values for various lookback periods and weights.

    """
    # pushes all na-values to the top of each column.
    arr, row, col = utils._push_nan(arr=price)
    tmp = np.full_like(arr, np.nan)
    number_nan_in_arr = np.count_nonzero(np.isnan(arr))
    first_moving_avg_value = (
        np.sum(arr[number_nan_in_arr : period + number_nan_in_arr]) / period
    )
    tmp[number_nan_in_arr + period] = first_moving_avg_value
    data_series = arr[number_nan_in_arr + period :].T
    period_factor = (period - 1) / period
    data_series_factor = period_factor ** np.arange(data_series.shape[1] - 1, -1, -1)
    wilders_moving_average = np.cumsum(
        data_series_factor * data_series
    ) / data_series_factor / period + first_moving_avg_value * (
        period_factor ** np.arange(1, data_series.shape[1] + 1)
    )
    wilders_moving_average_transpose = np.array([wilders_moving_average]).T
    out = np.vstack(
        (
            tmp[: number_nan_in_arr + period - 1],
            first_moving_avg_value,
            wilders_moving_average_transpose,
        )
    )
    # Re-arranges na-values back to original position
    out = utils._pull_nan(arr=out, row=row, col=col)

    if ffill:
        return utils._ffill_arr(arr=out)
    else:
        return out
```

Solution:
I dont know how to make it work with the np.apply.along_axis function.

I have a solution with pd.apply but the Data Form needs to be Numpy Arrays

Any Idea?

Comment: you don't need to use this `apply..`.  For 2d arrays it's no better than the obvious iteration.

Comment: @hpaulj do you know a solution?

Comment: `[func(arr[:,i] for i in range(7)]` or `[func(row) for row in arr.transpose()]`.  You know enough basic Python to write for loops and list comprehensions, don't you?

Comment: @hpaulj thanks. I thought there might be a solution without using a for loop. But then the for loop it is

Comment: Yes, there is a general "avoid loops" mantra in `numpy`, but that's not always optimal.  A few loops on a complex task may be easier, and even faster.  If you want fast, you have to either compild the function, or rewrite it from the core up to work with a 2d array.  `apply_along_axis` just hides the loop(s), and does not improve performance.